# JTable: change the status of a JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've a JTable and a column contains Boolean object, so its view in the table is a JCheckBox. I would like to change the status of the JCheckBox in order to change the data in my model. I set

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int y) {
   return true;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: If you're trying to do it through code, use `JCheckBox.setSelected()`.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Is the problem that your checkbox is not visible, you can not click it, you can not make it checked in code or you can not catch the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at TableModel, you'll notice the method [setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))(...). When you click the checkbox in the table, this is where this change will propogate.